# pandas array of integers to BigQuery using python

Tags: python, pandas, google-bigquery

I'm trying to load an array of integers from a pandas dataframe into BigQuery.
The load works well, but the array is empty (looses all the integers inside)

[image]

What am I missing here? Any ideas/suggestions?

```
tableId = test-dev.xpto.array
df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['name'] = ['city']
    df['channels'] = [[1, 13, 36]]

schema = [
    bigquery.SchemaField("name", "STRING", mode="NULLABLE"),
    bigquery.SchemaField("channels", "INT64", mode="REPEATED")
]
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig(
        schema=schema,
        create_disposition="CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
        write_disposition="WRITE_APPEND",
    )

job = client.load_table_from_dataframe(
            df, table_id, job_config=job_config
        )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried your code and it is working flawlessly. The only thing I've changed is the line `tableId = test-dev.xpto.array` to `table_id = 'my-project.my_dataset.my_table'` to match the argument in `job`.

[image]

Comment: very weird ... I'm doing exactly that, but my array keeps getting empty :(
my python version: Python 3.8.12
my version of API: google-cloud-bigquery=1.28.0

Any idea of what could be the problem?

Comment: Try creating the table again. Maybe there is a problem with the schema. Also, version 1.28.0 Is almost 2 years old. Try updating it.

Comment: Thanks Javier, it was the  google-cloud-bigquery API version ... with update, everything started to work as expected. Thanks!